# onRendered data not appearing unless I hit back button

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have some functionality in a `onRendered` event that I want to run on every render.

```
Template.DashboardCoachPost.onRendered(function () {
  var post, postId;

  this.autorun(function() {
    postId = Router.current().params.query.p;
    reactive.isSubmitted.set(false);

    if (Template.instance().subscriptionsReady()) {
      post = Posts.find({_id: postId}).fetch()[0];
      reactive.post.set(post);

      if (post) {
        reactive.isSubmitted.set(true);  
      }
    }
  });
});
```

In my RouterController I have:

```
DashboardCoachPostController = RouteController.extend({
  subscriptions: function() {
    this.postId = Router.current().params.query.p;

    if (this.handle) {
      this.handle.stop();
    }

    if (this.postId) {
      this.handle = this.subscribe('posts', { postId: this.postId });
    }
  }
});
```

and my route:

```
Router.route('/dashboard/coach/post', {
    name: 'dashboardCoachPost',
    controller: DashboardCoachPostController,
    where: 'client',
    layoutTemplate: 'LegalLayout'
});
```

I have a feeling that I am not handling subscriptions properly, but I can't figure out how to get my post without this method.

Answer (score 1):

`Template.instance().subscriptionsReady()` is used when you [subscribe in a template instance](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Blaze-TemplateInstance-subscribe). But you are [subscribing in the router](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#subscriptions).

You have to choose if you let the template instance handle the subscription or the router.